# TableViewCell not initializing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's my code:

[image: problem code]

The app compiles and runs without issue, and the first section of rows displays as expected. However, the second section doesn't even make it to the NSLog tick (though it does get as far as attempting to get a cell in the second section).

I'm confused as to why my second if(!cell) block never fires.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"foo";
static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"examplesCell";
if(indexPath.section == self.detailsSection) {
    NSLog(@"getting cell for indexPath: %@ (details)", indexPath);
    DetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[DetailTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.detail = [self.topic.details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
if(indexPath.section == self.examplesSection) {
    NSLog(@"getting cell for indexPath: %@ (examples)", indexPath);
    ReibunPagerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        NSLog(@"tick");
        cell = [[ReibunPagerTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];

    }
    cell.examples = self.examples;
    return cell;
}
UITableViewCell *emptyCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(!emptyCell){
    emptyCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...

return emptyCell;
}
```

Comment: Please, past your code (if someone needs to compilte your code)

Comment: sections are integers.  Are you returning the right number of sections in numberOfSectionsInTableView?  And also the right number of rows in numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: @OwenHartnett I think so. After all, the NSLog right before the if statement fires.

Comment: FYI, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: always returns a cell. So your `if (!cell)` checks are pointless.

Comment: One tip - `dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:` never returns nil

Comment: Does the method ever create an `emptyCell` object?

Comment: The only thing you do to put data into an example cell is cell.examples = self.examples;  This will make all these cells the same (or whatever self.examples is, assuming that both fields are NSStrings).  If they're something else, that may be why it doesn't display.

Comment: Th log shows that it is g thing into the second section code. Cell will never be nil, so you don't get "tick". Check what happens when cell.examples is set - it seems likely that the cell isn't rendered pretty based on that alone

Comment: aha. thank you very much. Neither if statement was firing. Back to the drawing board :-)